# fusioncharts ios onclick bar graph should take me to another window

Tags: ios, graph, charts, ios6, fusioncharts

How to achieve this using fusion charts on iOS: on-tap(ONclick) bar column should take me to another window with the information regarding that year.Thanks in advance.

Comment: There was not method to override and had breakpoints at multiple places but I did not get on click method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use link attribute for the column or bar data definition.

Example: `<set value='100' label='label' link='n-drilldownpage.asp?Id=9' />`